# how to access data in a SQL database without post backs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have an ASP.NET (VB codebehind) intranet site at work. We have Intermec scanners that we have created web apps for. The IE version on the scanners are "PIE" (Pocket Internet Explorer) which doesn't support AJAX or jQuery. The issue is I need to do several SQL calls in our app w/o post backs. My research tells me that javascript is the best way to go. So I need help confirming that this is possible with JavaScript, and if so how can I accomplish this. Or, find another way to do it inside my "PIE" browser? Mostly I will just be checking strings, but there were will be times I need to get a dataset and display it in a grideview (or tbl) all w/o a post back.

Thanks
Josh

UPDATE \ it appears there is evidence that suggests AJAX is available on PIE devices. So i'm willing to try an AJAX solution.

tks.

Comment: Are you sending back form data or is there just different data on different pages?

Comment: Pocket IE certainly does support AJAX.  See [here](http://xman892.blogspot.com/2006/10/ajax-and-pocket-pc.html) for some sample code.

Comment: @skyfoot - Yes. I will usually send a key of around 10ish characters. However, I could see a time where i wouldn't need to...

Comment: @PinnyM thanks for the link, I had read (and tested) a few things to the contrary. But this is good info. Do you have any links that may explain how I can accomplish what I need to with Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

If JQuery and AJAX *really* aren't options, you could always drop an IFRAME on your page, and dynamically alter the IFRAME url to query a different page, then read the page contents using javascript. It's hacky and ugly, but I've seen it work before.

Comment: yeah, some seem hacky... i will keep this in the back of my mind. Apparently AJAX does work on this device so if you can point me to a way to do that i would appreciate it!